# grid.abline (h=10) defined in grob object plotting a horizontal line of different intercept than what is specified before calling grid.draw(..)

Tags: r, grid

I was trying to use grid.draw() to plot a panel by specifying a grob object first with ylim=c(-60,60), horizontal intercept h=100:

```
plot2 <- df %>%

    select(SNP, series2) %>%

    na.omit() %>%

    ggplot() +

    geom_point(aes(x = SNP, y = series2), size = 1, alpha = 0.75,
               col=(1*(i<=8)+2*(i>8&i<=16)+3*(i>16))) +

    ylab("Bivariate-log10(p)") +

    ylim(c(-60,60))+

    theme_minimal() +

    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),

          axis.text.x = element_blank())+

    panel.abline(h=100,col=2,lty=2)
```

Then calling grid.draw :

```
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(ggplotGrob(plot2))
```

But the when I ran it, panel.abline draws a line at h=45 before I called grid.draw. When I decrease h to 10, it draws a line at h=70.

Then I took out the panel.abline part from the definition, instead putting it in grid.draw(..) as

```
grid.newpage()

grid.draw(ggplotGrob(plot2+panel.abline(h=100,col=2,lty=2)))
```

It gave me the same results, but plotted when grid.draw(..) command was called.

Anyone knows why it is plotting at the wrong intercept?

Thanks,

LOH

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add: The data I used could be

SNP=c('A','B','C','D','E');

series2=c(1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: why not use `geom_hline(yintercept = 10)`? btw `i` is not provided